# Why does Firefox remove "focus" of number input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I think this is a FF bug but maybe you know better?

1) User is typing into an `input[type="number"]`
2) When a condition is met, script adds a class to the `input`'s parent
3) This class causes the `input`'s parent to display some text via `:before`
4) The instant this happens, focus is kinda gone from the input, any more keystrokes go nowhere

This happens in Firefox, not Chrome, Safari, or IE. And by "focus kinda gone" I mean the element still has focus if you query the page and find which element has focus. But no keystrokes arrive and text doesn't go in.

Is this a bug in Firefox or some strange undocumented behaviour?

You can see this in action at http://jsbin.com/roruliti/10/edit. Enter '123' into text box. After entering '3', you'll need to click back into it to continue typing

My use case is: as user is entering credit card number, the parent `div` gains a checkmark (iconic font) by adding a character to the parent's :before the moment the card number is valid.

Comment: Works just fine here, Firefox 25.0.1.

Comment: Whoa... I see what you mean, but no idea how to fix it...  (I've got Firefox 29.0.1)

Comment: @Nit does FF 25 support the input[type="number"]? or does it just do a regular text box for that?

Comment: It is the same when you backspace the 3. In both scenario's a jQuery function is invoked that does something with the css class.